# Increment scraping using Scrapy on the URL

Tags: python, html, xpath, scrapy

I'm working on a project for university and I want to use scrappy to grab my test data. I want to be able to take a base url - such as store.steampowered.com/app/1 and move through the records so app/2, app/500, app/50000 (I imagine using regular expressions to define a set of rules) etc - But I can't seem to find out how to do it. I can't google it because it I don't know what its called!

I only want to pull a limited amount of data back, and I know how to do this for the individual pages using path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
['%s%d' % (base_url, x) for x in number_list]
```

number_list can be [1,2,3] or whatever number of data/app you need. 
If you want to set up rules, you are probably looking for a generator which will yield a number that follow your rules.